# Add random integer to every word in a file

Tags: python

I am creating a script that adds a random integer to every word in a file. All words are integer. So far my script add random integer if input is only one column.

```
import subprocess
import fileinput
import sys
from random import randint
#print randint(0,9)


for line in fileinput.input('mytext.txt', inplace=True):
    if int(line) < 999:
        line = int(line) + randint(25,101)
    else:
        line = int(line) + randint(50,500)

    line = str(line) + '\n'
    #print line
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This works if file contains below text ( One column )

```
1
2
3
4
```

Output:

```
94
2300
1402
585
```

But does not work if file contains: ( Two or more columns )

```
1   2
2   5
3   2
3   4
```

How to modify it, so that I can give as many columns as I want.

Comment: Have you tried: `columns = line.split()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the line and get the numbers, and then add your random number to the entire list of numbers:

```
for line in fileinput.input('mytext.txt', inplace=True):
    # get all numbers from row
    numbers = [int(x) for x in line.strip().split()]
    if numbers[0] < 999:
        numbers = [x + randint(25,101) for x in numbers]
    else:
        numbers = [x + randint(50,500) for x in numbers]
    # re-map modified numbers to a line of text
    sys.stdout.write(' '.join([str(x) for x in numbers]) + '\n')
```

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) instead of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) if you're more comfortable with it.

If you have something more complex in a csv-like format, use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).